# How to use nested foreach tag in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl, jsp-tags

I using Struts2 framework with JSP. I want to have nested `foreach` tag in JSP but I am getting below error at inner `foreach` tag.

Getting the error while iterating the nested objects from.

```jsp
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${dept.emplyees}">
```

**Exception:**

```java
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:274) ~[jstl-1.2.jar:1.2]
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:238) ~[jstl-1.2.jar:1.2]
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155) ~[jstl-1.2.jar:1.2]
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:291) ~[javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.jsp.views.Home.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(home_jsp.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.views.Home.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:159) ~[na:na]
```

Below is my sample code with POJO and Struts `Action` feilds.

**JSP Code:**

```jsp
<c:forEach var="dept" items="${deptList}"> 
  <c:out value="${dept.deptname}"/> 
  <c:forEach var="emp" items="${dept.emplyees}"> 
    <c:out value="${emp.name}"/> 
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

**Action class: `testAction`:**

```java
class TestAction{
List<Department> deptList

public List<Department> getDeptList() {
        return deptList;
    }

    public void setDeptList(List<Department> deptList) {
        this.deptList = deptList;
    }
}
```

**`Deprtment` POJO:**

```java
class Department{

private String deptname

List<Employee> emplyees;

    public List<Employee> getDeptList() {
        return emplyees;
    }

    public void setDeptList(List<Employee> emplyees) {
        this.emplyees = emplyees;
    }
}
```

**`Employee` POJO:**

```java
class Employee{
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: You have wrong getter and setter in Deprtment Pojo. Maybe it's just a copy error to post them here, but that's it. Also i STRONGLY suggest you to avoid dropping letters randomly, it will get only troubles to you. Turn emplyees into employees, for your own safety. Finally, is there any reason to not use s:iterator instead of forEach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over the property of the object it should be not `null` and have a getter method.

```
private List<Employee> emplyees = new ArrayList<>();
public List<Employee> getEmplyees() { return emplyees; }
```

Before displaying this property on the page, it would be nice to have some values. You can do this in the action, or better in `prepare()` and let your action implement [`Preparable` interface](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/preperable-interface.html).

> Often the data used to populate a form control is dynamically generated, perhaps from a database. When the user submits the form, the Struts 2 validation interceptor attempts to validate the user's form input. If validation fails the Struts 2 framework returns the value `"input"` but the `"input"` action is not re-executed. Rather the view associated with the `"input"` result is rendered to the user. Usually this view is the page that displayed the original form.
>
> This work-flow can cause a problem if one or more of the form fields or some other data displayed depends on a dynamic look-up that that is accomplished in the `Action` class's input method. Since the `Action` class's input method is not re-executed when validation fails, the view page may no longer have access to the correct information to create the form or other display information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked out. you are right, nested objects should be initialized in Action.